# Complex Queries - Get people with the most referrals

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make some sort of SQL Query where I only get the 10 people with the most referrals, but with minimum 1 referral.

My Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beta_list` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `referrer` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `referral_code` int(10) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
     email,
     referral_code as refcode,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM beta_list WHERE referrer=refcode) as referrals
  FROM 
     beta_list 
  WHERE
     referrals > 0
  ORDER BY
     referrals DESC
  LIMIT
     10
```

But it just says "Unknown column 'referrals' in 'where clause'".

I am no sql guru, I am only just beginning to learn more complex sql queries, so any help on how to achieve something like this would be deeply appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: whats the relation of refcode, referral and email. a little bit of more business will help a great deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - Add an outer query to extract the results from inner query -

```
select ref.email, ref.refcode, ref.referrals from 
(
  SELECT 
     email,
     referral_code as refcode,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM beta_list WHERE referrer=refcode) as referrals
  FROM 
     beta_list
) as ref
WHERE
     ref.referrals > 0
ORDER BY
     ref.referrals DESC
LIMIT
     10
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly, thanks a lot :)!
(need to wait 2 mins before I can accept the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT email,referral_code as refcode,count(*) as referrals
FROM beta_list 
WHERE referrer = referral_code
GROUP BY email,referral_code
ORDER BY referrals DESC
LIMIT 10;
```